# doubly linked list implementation

Tags: c++, data-structures

Which one would be more efficient?

I want to keep a list of items but, it's required of me to sort list

- by id,
- by name
- by course credits
- by the user

Would it be best to add items in list by id and then sort by the others or just add items without order and sort in the order needed when ever needed by the user?

Comment: first - how big you list is going to be?

Comment: @fazo: first would be, why a doubly-linked list ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're really required to keep the list sorted -- as opposed to using other data structures to give sorted access to the list -- then you could simply make a list whose elements have different pointers for different sort criteria.

In other words, instead of keeping just `previous` and `next` pointers, have `previousById`, `nextById`, `previousByName`, `previousByCredits` and `nextByCredits`. Likewise, you would have three head and/or tail pointers, instead of just one.

Please note that this approach has the drawback of being inflexible when it comes to implementing additional sort criteria. I'm assuming that you're trying to solve a homework-type problem, which is why I tried to tailor the answer to what seem to be the homework requirements.

Comment: I get the feeling that this is a homework assignment, and although I like this approach, and have done it before, I don't think it would satisfy his assignment.  Professors are a pain sometimes

Comment: @Greg Flynn: Yep, I still remember ;) That's why I put that disclaimer at the end of my answer. If it's a homework, it's hard to come up with a good solution without knowing the exact "boundaries" of it. Knowing what the professor is looking for would also help a lot.

Comment: i'm thinking to just unload the linked list in an array and sort it, instead of sorting the linked list directly

Comment: @Horace that would be a good idea since then when you unload the elements into an array, you're dealing with sequential blocks of memory whereas when you create new nodes in your linked list, they could be far apart, though I do suggest you do what I mentioned in my answer and keep the linked list sorted by one of the data members

Answer (score 2):

You can use three maps (or hashmaps):
One mapping the id to the item, one mapping name to an item reference (or pointer) and one mapping course credits to item reference again.

Comment: In addition to what @Ubiquite has said: If you can use Boost you can use Boost Bimap (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/one_minute_tutorial.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more efficient to sort it in whichever order that you know will be sorted for the most, for example if you know you're going to be retrieving by `id` most often, keep it sorted by `id`, otherwise pick one of the others though `id` would be the easiest if it is just an integer field

So then to do that you would check on insert to find where `newid` is less than `nextid` but greater than `previousid`, then allocate a new node with `new` and set the pointers appropriately.

Keeping the linked list sorted in some way is better than just keeping it unsorted.  You're adding some time to how long it takes to insert an item but it's negligible to how long it would take to sort it that particular way

Answer (score 1):

The more efficient would be to store the nodes as is, and keep 4 different indexes up-to-date. This way, when one order is required, you just pick up the right index and that's all. The cost is O(log N) for input, and O(1) for traversal.

Of course, keeping 4 indexes at once, with perhaps different requirements on uniqueness, and in the face of possible exceptions, is relatively difficult, but then, there's a Boost library for this: [Boost MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

On example is to generate a set that can be [sorted either by ID or by Name](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#multiple_sort).

Since you can add as many indexes as you wish, it should get you going :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep your lined list objects in the lined list, in random order. To sort the list by any key, use this pseudocode:

```
struct LinkedList {
    string name;
    LinkedList *prev;
    LinkedList *next;
};

void FillArray(LinkedList *first, LinkedList **output, size_t &size) {
    //function creates an array of pointers to every LinkedList object
    LinedList *now;
    size_t i; //you may use int instead of size_t

    //check, how many objects are there in linked list
    now=first;
    while(now!=NULL) {
        size++;
        now=now->next;
    }

    //if linked list is empty
    if (size==0) {
        *output=NULL;
        return;
    }

    //create the array;
    *output = new LinkedList[size];

    //fill the array
    i=0;
    now=first;
    while(now!=NULL) {
        *output[i++]=now;
        now=now->next;
    }
}

SortByName(LinkedList *arrayOfPointers, size_t size) {
    // your function to sort by name here
}

void TemporatorySort(LinkedList *first, LinkedList **output, size_t &size) {
    // this function will create the array of pointer to your linked list,
    // sort this array, and return the sorted array. However, the linked
    // list will stay as it is. It's good for example when your lined list
    // is sorted by ID, but you need to print it sorted by names only once.
    FillArray(first, *output, size);
    SortByName(output,size);
}

void PermanentSort(LinkedList *first) {
    // This function will sort the linked list and save the new order
    // permanently.
    LinkedList *sorted;
    size_t size;
    TemporatorySort(first,&sorted,size);
    if (size>0) {
        sorted[0].prev=NULL;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++) {
        sorted[i-1].next=sorted[i];
        sorted[i].prev=sorted[i-1];
    }
    sorted[size-1].next=NULL;
}
```

I hope, I actually did help you. If you don't understand any line from the code, simply put a comment to this "answer".

Comment: this is a good example but i'm required to do sorting and searching using the linked list(which i think is very inefficient)

Comment: @Horace Heaven: It is possible to implement QuickSort right onto the Linked List. But I don't have the code now, and it will take at least 30-60 minutes for me to write it... I don't have so much time.

Comment: @Horace Heaven: One more thing: The code I wrote IS for sorting a linked list :) but at first, it will load the list into an array of pointers (`FillArray` function), sort that array and return the sorted array only (`TemporatorySort` function). 

But it can also take the whole linked list, sort it and leave it sorted (`PermanentlySort` function).